# Setting up passwordless sudo on Linux distributions

Tags: linux, sudo, password

I recently set up both Fedora 28 & Ubuntu 18.04 systems and would like to configure my primary user account on both so that I can run `sudo` commands without being prompted for a password.

How can I do this on the respective systems?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is pretty trivial if you make use of the special Unix group called `wheel` on Fedora systems. You merely have to do the following:

1. Add your primary user to the `wheel` group

   ```
   $ sudo gpasswd -a <primary account> wheel
   ```
2. Enable NOPASSWD for the `%wheel` group in `/etc/sudoers`

   ```
   $ sudo visudo
   ```

   Then comment out this line:

   ```
   ## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
   # %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
   ```

   And uncomment this line:

   ```
   ## Same thing without a password
   %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

   Save this file with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
3. Logout and log back in

   **NOTE:** This last step is mandatory so that your desktop and any corresponding top level shells are re-execed showing that your primary account is now a member of the `wheel` Unix group.

Comment: What would change if instead of `wheel` you used any other group?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Change `%wheel` to that group.

Answer (score 26):

Traditionally on Debian based distributions such as Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/Kali/Antix, the default group for sudo is, well, `sudo`.

So to add passwordless `sudo` enabled users to a Debian based system, the steps are:

1. Install `sudo`

   In Debian, depending on the installation options, you often end up without `sudo` installed by default.

   If the package `sudo` is not installed (e.g. you do not have `/etc/sudoers`), run as root:

   ```
   # apt install sudo
   ```
2. Add the user to the sudo group

   Add a user to the sudo group, if it is not already in the sudo group  (Ubuntu and derivatives add a user created in installation automatically to the sudo group).

   When setting up the first sudo user, you have got to the first as `root`:

   ```
   # gpasswd -a <primary account> sudo
   ```

   When you already have a `sudo` user, it is advised as good security practice, to set up the other users in the sudo group via that user:

   ```
   $ sudo gpasswd -a <primary account> sudo
   ```
3. Modify `/etc/sudoers` for adding the NOPASSWD directive

   You then edit the default line in `/etc/sudoers` for the `sudo` group with:

   ```
   $ sudo visudo
   ```

   and change it from:

   ```
   # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

   to:

   ```
   # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command, no password
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```
4. Logout and log back in

   If logged in the system, the intended user has then to logout and login for the change of the user belonging to the `sudo` group to take effect.

**NOTE:** In Debian the group `wheel` is often used to restrict in PAM the use of `su` to a group, instead of using it for the `sudo` command as in RedHat/SuSE based distributions.

Traditionally in Debian based distributions, for the `sudo` command you use the `sudo` group.

Answer (score 7):

Most distributions have this line in `/etc/sudoers/`:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Consequently, an easy way to add one user is to create a suitable file in the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory; I normally name it for the user to be added:

```
add_sudoer() {
    if ! test -n "$1"
    then echo "Usage: $0 <user>" >&2; return
    fi

    printf >"/etc/sudoers.d/$1" '%s    ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL\n' "$1"
}
```

You might also want to add `Defaults:%s    !lecture, !authenticate\n` and/or other options to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you can use Python [pudo](https://pypi.org/project/pudo/1.0.0/) package.

Installation:

```
user$ sudo -H pip3 install pudo # you can install using pip2 also
```

Below is the code snippet for using in python automation for running commands under root privilege::

```
user$ python3 # or python2
>>> import pudo
>>> (ret, out) = pudo.run(('ls', '/root')) # or pudo.run('ls /root')
>>> print(ret)
>>> 0
>>> print(out)
>>> b'Desktop\nDownloads\nPictures\nMusic\n'
```

Below is the cmd example for running commands under root privilege

```
user$ pudo ls /root
Desktop  Downloads  Pictures  Music
```